# The commutant of reduced C*-algebra of a discrete group

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For a discrete group $\Gamma$ we let $\lambda: \Gamma \rightarrow B(l^{2}(\Gamma))$ denote the *left regular representation* and $\rho$ denote the *right regular representation*. The reduced C*-algebra of $\Gamma$, denoted $C^{*}_{\lambda}(\Gamma)$,is the completion of $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ with respect to the norm 
$$||x||_{r}=||\lambda(x)||_{B(l^{2}(\Gamma))}$$
Similarily, we can define $C^{*}_{\rho}(\Gamma)$.

My question is: do we have that $C_{\lambda}^{*}(\Gamma)'=C^{*}_{\rho}(\Gamma)$? Here, $C_{\lambda}^{*}(\Gamma)'$ denote the commutant of $C_{\lambda}^{*}(\Gamma).$

Comment: Observe that $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)^\prime$, as a commutant, is weakly closed, whilst $C_\rho^\ast(\Gamma)$ generally isn't; what you should have instead is $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)^\prime = C_\rho^\ast(\Gamma)^{\prime\prime}$.

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić Oh, does $C_{\lambda}^{*}(\Gamma)'=C^{*}_{\rho}(\Gamma)''$ hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double commutant of $C^*_\lambda(\Gamma)$ is usually called the *group von Neumann algebra* of $\Gamma$, and denoted by $L(\Gamma)$. Similarly, the double commutant of $C^*_\rho(\Gamma)$ is denoted (I don't think this notation is as standard as the previous one) by $R(\Gamma)$.

It is well-known that $L(\Gamma)'=R(\Gamma)$, and it immediately follows that $R(\Gamma)'=L(\Gamma)$. As the triple commutant agrees with the first one, you have
$$
C^*_\rho(\Gamma)'=C^*_\lambda(\Gamma)'',\ \ C^*_\lambda(\Gamma)'=C^*_\rho(\Gamma)''
$$

Comment: Thanks, Martin. In which book I can find this results?

Comment: I learned that from Theorem 6.7.2 in Kadison-Ringrose. I'm fairly certain that it should be in Takesaki's book, but I don't have a reference.